# Workflow should trigger only once

Tags: workflow

I want my workflow to execute only once for a record. For example: I am having an opportunity when it reaches the Amount of $10000, it should trigger an email from workflow. It is happening now. But when it comes below to $10000 and reaching $10000 again it is sending the email again, which should not happen in my scenario.

Note: I tried using sales force default big deal alert functionality. But, in my case it cannot be used.

Please help in this.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a Field like checkbox and Whenever this criteria met, Update the Checkbox from the Workflow Itself....So that the next time editing, it won't be fired if you put this in the Criteria level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a WF and use criteria and set it to created and any time edited and and create a checkbox.

Now put a formula `Amount >= $10000` and checkbox is false

And in WF action send an email and update the checkbox to true. so this will run only once.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I update that checkbox once sent the email?

Comment: @karthikkarthik create a field update and set it to true.